# как лучше реализовать бд под мазагин

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

делать внешние ключи? например имеем товар с категорией, размерами и подобными колонками. вот вопрос, выносить ли все эти колонки в разные таблицы, и ссылаться на них уже в основной табличке товара?

Comment: или может еще что посоветуете, хочу сделать проект максимально правильно, а не абы как

Comment: Если делаете подобный проект впервые - вы в любом случае сделаете неправильно, так что особо заморачиваться смысла нет. А подсказать, как лучше проектировать БД - невозможно, не зная предметной области.

Comment: но все же, какие можете дать советы?

Comment: Обычно нужно делать отдельные таблицы. В общем, приводить к 3-НФ.

Comment: Да, выносить. Это называется "нормализация"